# Cannot convert nil to type string

Tags: go

I have this piece of code in a middleware func:

```
params := r.URL.Query()

tok := params["x-huru-api-token"][0];

if tok == nil {
    tok := r.Header.Get("x-huru-api-token")
}
```

but I get this error:

[image]

anybody know what that's about?

Comment: `nil` is not a valid `string` type value, hence you cannot compare with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value `nil` is not a valid value for a `string`.  If you want to fallback to the header on both missing values and empty values, then using the following code:

```
params := r.URL.Query()
tok := params.Get("x-huru-api-token")
if tok == "" {
    tok = r.Header.Get("x-huru-api-token")
}
```

If you only want to fallback to the header when the query parameter is missing, then use the following:

```
params := r.URL.Query()
var tok string
if values, ok := params["x-huru-api-token"]; ok && len(values) > 0 {
   tok = values[0]  // note that tok can be the empty string ""
} else {
   tok = r.Header.Get("x-huru-api-token")
}
```

Note one difference between the code in this answer and the question.  This answer uses assignment to set `tok` inside the if statement.  The code in the question uses a short variable declaration. The short variable declaration will not compile because the newly declared variable inside the if statement is not used.

Answer (score 4):

String is not a pointer type in Go therefore it cannot be `nil`. Zero value for string is empty string ("").

The correct code should be:

```
params := r.URL.Query()

tok := params["x-huru-api-token"][0];

if tok == "" {
    tok := r.Header.Get("x-huru-api-token")
}
```